# jQuery String replace repetitive special characters with different variables

Tags: jquery, replace

How can I achieve the following using JQuery.

`string = 'This $ should be greater than $ always'`.

in my case the above string also a variable, any replace function to replace `$` with different variables, say

`replace(string, var1, var2)`.

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/tq9et7bo/7/

Comment: You're probably looking for the built-in [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) function which takes a `replacement` function as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks MKA, Simon it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinventing the wheel is not necessary here i guess but there is a jQuery plugin here [jQuery.validator.format()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
var template = jQuery.validator.format("{0} is not a valid value");
// later, results in 'abc is not a valid value'
alert(template("abc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace $ sign with another character try this:.

```
var s = "This is a string $ that contains $, a special character.";
s = s.replace(/\$/g, '*'); // use character instead of * according to you requirement.
```

I hope it will work. Here is the exmaple :-http://phpidiots.in/jquery/replace-special-character-with-another-character-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I believe you want to replace `$` with different values. For example, if var1 is `val1` and var2 is `val2` your original string `This $ should be greater than $ always` once replaced should look like `This val1 should be greater than val2 always`

Provided that the number of `$` symbols in your string is always equal to the number of values to be replaced, here is a solution. Note that I am using an array to hold the variable values.

credit to @Alnitak for the replaceAt function (refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784637/replacing-character-at-a-particular-index-with-a-string-in-javascript-jquery))

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfxy644v/1/)

```
var string = 'This $ should be greater than $ always';
arr = ["val1", "val2"];

$.each(arr, function(k,v){
    string = replaceAt(string,string.indexOf('$'), v);
});

$('#display').html(string);

// replace the 'n'th character of 's' with 't'
function replaceAt(s, n, t) {
    return s.substring(0, n) + t + s.substring(n + 1);
}
```