# Jquery, Given a string and its coordinates replace it

Tags: jquery

I have a string like that:

> I'm a string not too long but neither so short

Let's take the word 'not' inside the string: it starts at position number 13 and it ends at position numer 16.

There's a way with JQuery to substitute the word between position 13 and position 16 with this:

```
<b>not</b>
```

I know only the position of the string that i want to replace not it's content.

Comment: Try having a look at this

[Replacing at particular index][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: This should not require any jQuery.  A few plain JavaScript string functions and you're good.  I know what you mean, though - I always look to jQuery first, but sometimes plain JavaScript will do it without any fuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mostly use good old-fashioned JavaScript to do this, but you can use jQuery for the DOM manipulation (though you don't *have* to).

http://jsfiddle.net/hQUhX/

contents:

```
function replacePiece(str, start, end) {
   var component = str.substr(start, end - start);
   var newstr = str.substr(0,13) + "<b>" + component + "</b>"
      + str.substr(end);
   return newstr;
}

​$("#Str").html(replacePiece($("#Str").text(), 13, 16));
```

Comment: If you don't even know the starting position, but know the word, you can use `indexOf` method to get the index of that word.. something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQUhX/28/)

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for replacing when you ONLY know the STARTING position**

What I ended up doing is answering based on only knowing the starting position, not the end position of the word.

What this does is grab the string from the known starting position, split it by spaces, then wrap the first word with `<b>`, then adds that back in between the string and outputs that.

**JSFiddle Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/Jc829/4/

Sorry for not paying more attention the first time around.

Also, you don't really need jQuery for this.

Comment: Your fiddle produces the string `not` in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the wrapping part.  Working on it now.  I apologize.

Comment: Check my updated answer to see if this if more of what you want.

Comment: it seems that Explosion Pills answered before, i'll accept his one

Comment: That's alright, I updated my answer for those who stumble upon this and want to know how to replace it with only knowing the starting position.

Answer (score 0):

While I've accepted Explosion Pills answer I think this is a more polished way to do this (thanks to Matthew Riches for the link)

```
String.prototype.replacePiece = function(replace_with, start, end) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + replace_with + this.substring(end, this.length)
}

var str = "Helloiworld";

var replace_with = "<b>i</b>";

alert(str.replacePiece(replace_with, 5, 6));​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paglia_s/QTMJG/