# Replace certain characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

After consulting multiple answers on this site, I am still unable to find a solution for how to replace certain characters in a string in Javascript.  I've tried using .replace() with regular expressions to no avail.

For context, here is what I have:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var button = document.getElementById('myBtn');

button.onclick = function() {
   var splitter = text.value.split(" ");
   for(var i=0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
  if(splitter[i].match("er$")) {
    splitter[i].replace(/er$/, "x"); <----The one line causing me insanity.

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace ?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: What is happening exactly other than causing insanity?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the input, what is the output and what is the output you expect?

Comment: I am trying to replace the final two characters of all words in a given string that match a certain condition. It is returning the original string.

Answer (score 2):

A string in javascript is immutable, so [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new one.

You probably want

```
splitter[i] = splitter[i].replace(/er$/, "x");
```

Note also that you don't have to test if it matches before, and that you might do the whole operation without splitting (by using `\b` for word boundaries with this regular expression : `/er\b/g`).

Comment: You may also just want to get rid of the if block that starts if(splitter[i].match("er$")) {. Since you're doing the match, you're essentially running the regular expression twice when it matches and once when it doesn't, why not just run it once on the replace.

Comment: @Dante617 That's what I meant with *"you don't have to test if it matches before"*. But your comment might make it more clear.

Comment: Yeah, made the comment before you made the edit. :)

Comment: The only thing is I'm actually checking to see if the words in the string end with "er."

Comment: Yes but you don't have to : just let replace do the replacement, it won't replace anything if there is no word in the string ending with "er".

Comment: @Nick D. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm53z/).

Answer (score 0):

You can you this techinque as described here:

[How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
   }
```

and use as following

```
var hello="Hello World";
alert(hello.replaceAt(3, "a"));
```