# How to replace characters by index in a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace, substring

If  I have the string "hello" and I want to replace the second and third character with _, how can i do that, given only the location of the substring, not what it actually is.

Comment: I tried the replace() method, but you need a substring for that, not just the location @Sednus

Comment: Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str = str.replace( /^(.)../, '$1__' );
```

The `.` matches any character except a newline.

The `^` represents the start of the string.

The `()` captures the character matched by the first `.` so it can be referenced in the replacement string by `$1`.

Anything that matches the regular expression is replaced by the replacement string `'$1__'`, so the first three characters at the start of the string are matched and replaced with whatever was matched by the first `.` plus `__`.

Comment: [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is really helpful to learn more about JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: He can, but it is better to look into replace() and Regular Expressions:


http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

 / and this / 

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 9):

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
   }

str.replaceAt(1,"_");
str.replaceAt(2,"_");
```

Taken from: [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)