# Hangman implementation

Tags: javascript

**SITUATION**

I started to implement the game "HANGMAN" using only JavaScript and HTML on client side machines. I have completed all the logical work. Now only the aesthetics are remaining. And I am stuck up because we can't write to strings in JS.

`a = "abcd"; a[0] = "e";` -- This type of thing is not allowed.

**What I have done**

## CODE

The code I have tried, This does not work:

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/IcyFlame/AVtb9/)

I now have the following three arrays:

`a` -- The array that contains the letters of the word(for `gel` this would be `g,e,l`)

`gai` -- This array consists of the letters that have been entered by the user and are there in the word.(like `g` or `e`)

`ag` -- This array consists of the letters that have been entered by the user regardless of whether or not they are there in the word to be guessed or not.

**What I need to do**

I need to generate the output that would show the letter in case it has been guessed by the user and is there in the word(letters in the array `gai`) and `_` in place of letters that have not yet been entered by the user.

**What I want**

A function that will return the desired output, as explained in the following example.

**Example**

Let the word to be guessed be:

`together`

User enters `e`:

The function should return: `_ _ _ e _ _ e _`

User then enters `d`, my program will prompt him to say that this letter is not there in the word.

User enters `r`

Function should return: `_ _ _ e _ _ e r`

And so on....

I hope you get the idea!

In case you don't get it(owing to my bad explanation or otherwise!!)

You can play a game of hangman here: [Hangman](http://www.hangman.no/)

Just watch the output at the bottom of the screen... Thats what I want this function to generate.

**Kindly** help me with this issue!

Comment: You have described what you have done, but no code has been provided? Re-creating it on jsfiddle.net would help, or you **must** provide all the information required for us to re-create the entire functionality required to look at the problem. This includes all HTML/CSS/JavaScript code. Link to it if you have a live page.

Comment: so, you want us to show you how to replace the characters in some word not on some list with underscores and stitch with spaces?

Comment: **Of course you can write to an array** A=[10,20,30]; A[1]=15; console.log(A); yields [10,15,30]

Comment: @Paul you can't write to a string, however

Comment: @JanDvorak You can indirectly, with `split` and `join`.

Comment: or make a new one with replace

Comment: @Doorknob ... as OTK has shown. But is it an obvious approach?

Comment: @Doorknob: That indirect method is what I am looking for here!

Comment: @IcyFlame Then see [the answer that was provided to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17741439/1223693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can use this function to set char at specified index of string:

```
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading just the start of your question (because no other code is provided), there is a problem which could be solved using native javascript functions.

```
var strarr = "Hello world!".split(''); // this will give you an array of characters to be manipulated
strarr[6] = "X"; // so you can do this
console.dir(strarr.join('')); // test it!
```

As an idea (not mine, its from comments) one could even wrap this simple code as a missing toCharArray() function and use that.

Another thing is that this method is fast enough even for relatively large bulk of text. For a test I used lorem ipsum with 1000 words. On my rather old dev machine, manipulation executes in milliseconds.

For more information, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript/17747861#17747861).

Comment: @bukko I wish it were possible to down vote comments.

Comment: Bukko disappeared, but his Java-styled idea is not bad. One could wrap this simple code as a missing toCharArray() function and use that.

Comment: @Aadit No need to be spiteful, we all make mistakes...

Answer (score -1):

You could use regex to mask letters in a word using `String.replace`.

```
var word = "together"
  , correct = "";

function guess(c) {
  if (word.indexOf(c) > -1) {
    correct += c;
  }
  console.log(word.replace(new RegExp("[^" + correct + "]", "g"), "_"));
}
```