# Make a character capitalize within a strin in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase

I am trying to capitalize a character within a string in javascript, my codes are :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "string";
    for(m = 0; m < str.length; m++){
    if(str[m] == "r"){
      str[m+1] = str[m+1].toUpperCase();
    }
    }
    alert(str);
}
</script>
```

So what I am trying to do is, if the character is `r`,capitalize the next character. But is not woking means its the same string alerting.

Comment: AFAIR, I don't think you can modify it `using str[x]=...`. Use `str.substring` along with `toUpperCase`

Comment: There is a SO that seems to be the same question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript) but I like @elclanrs' answer better...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable, you need to create a new string and concatenate:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "string";
  var res = str[0];
  for(var m = 1; m < str.length; m++){
    if(str[m-1] == "r"){
      res += str[m].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      res += str[m];
    }
  }
}
```

But you could simply use regex:

```
'string'.replace(/r(.)/g, function(x,y){return "r"+y.toUpperCase()});
```

Comment: he wants the character after the r to be upper case, not the r

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood the question a bit, thx @anishsane

Comment: @eclanrs He want to Capitalize the next character. Not "r"

Comment: @anishsane, yeah, but I wanted to demonstrate the callback, because the regex could be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

`String` are immutable. So You can convert `string` to `array` and do the replacements and then convert `array` to `string`. `Array` are mutable in Javascript.

```
var str = "string".split('');
for(m = 0; m < str.length - 1; m++){
if(str[m] == "r"){
  str[m+1] = str[m+1].toUpperCase();
}
}
alert(str.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var p='';
var old="r";
var newstr =old.toUpperCase();
var str="string";
while( str.indexOf(old) > -1)
      {

        str = str.replace(old, newstr);
}
alert(str);
}
</script>
```

But you it will not work in alart.
Hope it helps

Comment: Not `"entire string".toUpperCase()`... He wants a specific character to be upper cased.

Comment: sorry i edited the answer it will work now and @V.J alert can also show the uppercase string was my fault. please apologize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "string";
    for(m = 0; m < str.length; m++){ // loop through all the character store in varable str.
        if(str[m] == "r") // check if the loop reaches the character r.
        {
           alert(str[m+1].toUpperCase()); // take the next character after r make it uppercase.
        }
    }
```