# Change a single character of a string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I've this variable in JavaScript:

```
var aString = '00000'
```

and I want to change the value of the 4th character from '0' to 'b'. I've tried this

```
aString[3] = 'b'
```

but `aString` doesn't change the value.
How can I do this?

Comment: strings in javascript is **immutable**..refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: jQuery doesn't have string manipulation methods (except `.trim()`). This is all pure JavaScript.