# JavaScript Array map function won't change elements in a String?

Tags: javascript

So I've tried to use the map() method as follows:

```
words = ["One", "Two"];
words = words.map(function(currentValue)
    {
        alert(currentValue[0]);//Output: O Then: T
        currentValue[0] = "A";
        alert(currentValue[0]);//Output: O Then: T
        return currentValue;
    });
```

Why is it that currentValue[0] is not getting assigned the value "A"?!?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempting to assign to a string at a specific position via its index, this is not possible as Strings are immutable.  If you want to change a string you need to create a new one.

Comment: Can you explain how alert(currentValue[0]) alerts the character? I mean here the immutable String is treated as an array?

Comment: You can *read* using the `string[pos]` syntax but you cannot *write* to the string - if you could do that you would have a string that contained a different value from the one it was created with, and JavaScript disallows this (immutability).

Answer (score 1):

As Alex K correctly points out, strings are immutable and you cannot modify them.

Since you are using a `.map()`, the thing to do here is just construct a new string and return that:

```
var words = ["One", "Two"];

words = words.map(function (currentValue) {
    return "A" + currentValue.substring(1);
});

console.log(words); // outputs ["Ane", "Awo"];
```

As a rule of thumb, you should not try to use `.map()` to modify existing values. The purpose of `.map()` is to produce a new set of values, and leave the original ones untouched.

Comment: Good to know about that rule of thumb. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `String` is the primitive type, so you cannot mutate it.

**String , Number , Boolean, Null, Undefined, Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)** are primitive types.

Comment: Wait really? Does that mean String is not an Object?!

Comment: That's correct. `"" instanceof Object` produces `false`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects