# .replace always putting the character in the first position

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a hangman game. I need to replace the underscores in the variable "underscore" with the letter in the variable "letter" when the letter matches what's in the variable "word". Any way of doing this?

```
for( i = 0; i < word.length; i++ ) {
    if (word[i] === letter) {
        underscore = underscore.replace(underscore.charAt(i*2), letter);
    }
}
```

Above is the specific part of my code that I have trying to replace it at the moment but it will only replace the next underscore after a letter/beginning no matter what I do. Below is my full code if you need any more details of how it works.

Thanks in advance.

```css
/* Hangman Game CSS File */
body
{
 background-color: #1B264F;
}

#main {
 background-color: #5386E4;
 height: 97vh; 
    width: 95vw;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hangman by Lachlan Teale</title> 
  <meta name="description" content="Lachlan Teale's Hangman Game 2015">
  <meta name="keywords" content="hangman, lachlan, teale, Javascript">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Lachlan Teale">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="main" width="1920" height="1080" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //setting variables
  var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var underscore = "";
       var letter;
       var complete = false;

 //list of words
  var wordList = ["apple", "peach", "pear", "mango", "banana", "paper", "pens", "laptop", "desk", "chair", "star", "sky", "moon", "sun", "planets"];

 //picking a random word from the list
  var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

 //print out the underscores for the number of letters
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   var underscore = underscore + "_ ";
  }

  context.font = '50pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

    //correct letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Correct Letters", canvas.width * 0.08, canvas.height * 0.05);

    //Wrong Letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Wrong Letters", canvas.width - (canvas.width * 0.08), canvas.height * 0.05);

 //checking which button is pressed
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   if ( event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 ) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
          letter = String.fromCharCode( event.keyCode ).toLowerCase();
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
        }
  });

 //checking if back key is pressed
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if ( event.keyCode == 8 ) {              
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
      }
     });

 //checking if enter is pressed
       document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {

    //checking if letter is in the word
       alert(word);
            
    for( i = 0; i < word.length; i++ ) {
     if (word[i] === letter) { 
         underscore = underscore.replace(underscore.charAt(i*2), letter);
     }
    }

    context.clearRect(canvas.width * 0.4, canvas.height * 0.3, canvas.width *0.7, canvas.height * 70);
       context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

         alert(underscore); 
   }
     }); 

  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: probabily referring to the accepted answer in this thread will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Since all the characters in the string `underscore` are "_", when you run `underscore.replace(underscore.charAt(i*2), letter);` 
it looks through the string for the character at `i*2`, and then replaces the first instance of that character with `letter` (you can find a doc for this here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

What you may want to do instead is to define a function like the following:

```
function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

and use that function instead of `replace()`

You can declare that function and then call it where you called `.replace()` before. When you call it, just replace `str` with the string (`underscore`), `index` with the index where you want the new letter, and `ltr` with the new letter you want (`letter`).

Comment: That looks like what I want to do, but as I'm new to this and have no clue where to start, could you possibly show me how i'd put this into my code?

Comment: Edited to be a bit more in depth

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to up vote and accept if it answers your question!
Thanks!

Comment: Tried editing it to get it to work, no luck I'm sorry. I'm quite terrible at this stuff, any chance of a jsfiddle or something?