# JS/JQUERY not updating string array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, string

I am facing a problem with a web application I am making.

I am using `node.js` for backend and the server is sending (using `socket.io`) a string like this "`0010000110�0`".

On the client side I have:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(){

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
var tmpData = [];

socket.on('recData', function(data){
    tmpData = data; //here I put the received string in the tmpData array
});

//checking for the string array state
$("#deskLight-1").on("vclick", function(){
        if(tmpData[2] == '1'){
            tmpData[2] = '0';
            alert(tmpData);
        }   
        else if(tmpData[2] == '0'){
            tmpData[2]='1';
            alert(tmpData);
        }   
    });

});
```

So the idea is to turn on/off the light. This is just part of the code, so lets focus on the `tmpData[2]` only.

The if condition works correctly and the alert dialog shows only the old tmpData string (so this one `0010000110�0`). And it should be changed to this `00**0**0000110�0`

I dont understand why `tmpData[2] = '0'` or `tmpData[2] = '1'` doesn't update the indexed value. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try once with `tmpData = data.split('')` and then `alert(tmpData.join(''))`

Comment: Strings in JavaScript are immutable, so to change something in string you have to create new one. Something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable:

```
var str = '123';
str[1] = 'x';
console.log(str); // '123'
```

You seem to want to use your data as an array of characters, so store it as an array:

```
socket.on('recData', function(data){
    tmpData = data.split(''); // array of characters
});
```

Remember to join the characters together if you need the (updated) string back:

```
console.log(tmpData.join(''));
```