# Replacing multiple characters in a string with a string rewrites characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a variable (in this example `var str = "I!%1$s-I!%2$s TTL!%3$s";`), in which I want to replace the `%` with elements from an array (`var regex = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];`).

I google around a bit and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript), but I'm having trouble implementing it. My problem is that I want to replace a single character with multiple characters, and then continue the string, but this just overwrites the characters. I actually have no idea why.

Any help is appreciated, my code below

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
}

var str = "I!%1$s-I!%2$s TTL!%3$s";
var regex = ['replace', 'replace', 'replace'];

//find position of %
var find = /%/gi,
  result, pos = [];
while ((result = find.exec(str))) {
  pos.push(result.index);
}

//replace % with regex elements
for (x = 0; x < pos.length; x++) {
  str = str.replaceAt(pos[x], regex[x]);
}

document.write(str);
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why is using the replace method of a string not an option?

Comment: Because you're not updating `pos`. If we have a string `"abc"`, here `"c"` is the 3rd character. If we replace `"b"` with `"foo"` (`"afooc"`), `"c"` is now the 5th character.

Comment: If I got you right you need to replace te % characters in string with corresponding values from your regex array where index of value corresponds to occurance number of % character in string?

Comment: because the array elements are not always the same (.replace replaces all instances of % with a string). I guess I put in a bad example, I'll go edit it out

Comment: @DušanRadojević yes, that's correct

Comment: In that case you can even do string.replace in a loop since it will always replace the first occurance of % character... But I vote for @thefourtheye answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), like this

```
var str = "I!%1$s-I!%2$s TTL!%3$s";
var regex = ['[123]', '[456]', '[789]'];

console.log(str.replace(/%(\d+)/g, function(match, group1) {
  return regex[parseInt(group1) - 1] + group1;
}));
// I![123]1$s-I![456]2$s TTL![789]3$s
```

The RegEx `/%(\d+)/g` matches anything of the pattern `%` followed by one or more digits. And it captures the digits as a group. Then the exact match and the group is passed to the function to get the actual replacement. In the function, you convert the group to a number with `parseInt` and return the respective value from the `regex` array.

Comment: this doesn't take space into account, and misses a character at the 3rd replacement (the 3 gets overwritten)

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič What is the expected output for the inputs I have shown?

Comment: `I![123]1$s-I![456]2$s TTL![789]3$s` sorry, it's actually a problem with all 3 numbers (one character still gets overwritten)

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Then just attach the group as well in the replacement. Please take a look at the updated answer.