# Function to change placement of characters in a string not working. (JS)

Tags: javascript

Now I am about to share a small code, which is not working and I don't have any idea why the heck it is not working:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Stack Overflow</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="targetField">Please Enable Javascript</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function changeString(stringA , a , b){
    var character = stringA.charAt(a);
    stringA.charAt(a) = stringA.charAt(b);
    stringA.charAt(b) = character;
    return stringA;
}

var stringB = changeString("This is javascript" , 1 , 2 );
document.getElementById('targetField').textContent = stringB;
```

This looks very wierd. Can someone please tell me the problem. (I hope there is no syntax error)

Comment: Strings are **immutable**. You cannot have a **value** on the LHS of an assignment.

Comment: But isn't `stringA.charAt(a)` a value, because it returns 'h' ?

Comment: ohhhhh.... Any alternatives?

Comment: You probably want to use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and create a new string.

Comment: Okay, thnx @FelixKling

Answer (score 0):

You will find an answer 
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

`.chartAt(index)` is a function and returns the character at the specified index. It does not let you set a character!

If you want to change the string you have to create a new one.