# Replace the last dash value from a data attribut?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var dataUrl = $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url");

// http://localhost:8888/app/status/get/31/7
```

I need to change the last value of the link from the last dash (7) by another value. 
7 is a dynamic value.

Ho can i do it ?

For instance if i want to change the dynamic value 7 by 9 :

```
var new = 9;
$("#AjaxMoreStatus").attr("data-url", url without the 7 + '/' + new);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to change the last 7 for other thing, try this code:

```
var dataUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/app/status/get/31/7';
var newValue = 9;

dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(/([0-9])$/i, newValue);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hf6ra8k/1/

Hope it may help you :).

Answer (score 6):

use `lastIndexOf` to check the index of last occurrence of "/"

```
var dataUrl = $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url");

var newValue = 9;

dataUrl = dataUrl.substring( 0, dataUrl.lastIndexOf( "/" ) ) + "/" + newValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()` to separate the pieces of the url and replace the last item:

```
 var url = "http://localhost:8888/app/status/get/31/7";
 url = url.replace("http://", "").split("/");
 var newValue = "9";

 url[(url.length - 1)] = newValue;

 var newUrl = "http://"+url.join("/");
```

Comment: I thought of `split()` too, but just couldn't figure out replacing last value :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace` method just like here

```
var url = "http://localhost:8888/app/status/get/31/7";
a.replace(/\/(\d*)$/, '/' + newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.lastIndexOf()` to find the `index`. Then you can replace value at that index. For reference, refer following post: [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript).

```js
var url = "htt[://stacloverflow.com/test/param/tobe/replaced/with/newValue";
var newVal = "testNewValue";

var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = url.substring(0,lastIndex+1) + newVal;
alert(result)
```