# Can't assign letter by index. Is it implicit conversion error?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the noob question, I new in JS. Can't assign letter by index

```
var str="some string";
for( var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    var letter=str[i];    // it works
    letter.toUpperCase(); // it works too
    str[i]=letter; // try to assign new letter by index, but nothing happens..
}
```

Maybe is it because of implicit conversion from string to char..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in JS.

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This
>   means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it.
>   However, it is still possible to create another string based on an
>   operation on the original string.

You need to write your own function to assemble a new string out of the existing one.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: or the FP way, `str.split('').map(function (s) {
  return s.toUpperCase();
}).join('')`