# Changing array by map() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change array with map() but it doesn't work. 
Here is my code.

```
const colors = ["#9abc9c", "#9ecc71", "#9498db", "#9b59b6", "#967e22", "#974c3c", "#91c40f"];
colors.map(color => color[1]="1");
```

Input what i want is change every first number after "#" into 1.

```
colors = ["#1abc9c", "#1ecc71", "#1498db", "#1b59b6", "#167e22", "#174c3c", "#11c40f"];
```

I'd be so appreciate it if you let me solve this problem.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? What should be the expected result?

Comment: `map` always returns a new array. Here it will return an array of `'1'`

Comment: I suggest looking at [examples of using `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#examples).

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `color[1] = "1"` will do nothing.

Comment: Also, strings are immutable, you can't change them by assigning to their letters. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874666/cant-assign-letter-by-index-is-it-implicit-conversion-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: @Pointy - I already voted differently (because I'm silly), but you might want to VTC as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874666/cant-assign-letter-by-index-is-it-implicit-conversion-error or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: Map doesn't change arrays, Map creates copies. Cease modifying arrays as simple as that one. Just create a new array with map, instead of modifying the existing array.

Comment: my expected input is `["#1abc9c", "#1ecc71", "#1498db", "#1b59b6", "#167e22", "#174c3c", "#11c40f"]`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's always hard to vote when there are layers of competing errors :)

Answer (score 2):

**`SOLUTION 1`**

If you want to replace first character after `#` with `1` then you can do as:

```js
const colors = [
    '#9abc9c',
    '#9ecc71',
    '#9498db',
    '#9b59b6',
    '#967e22',
    '#974c3c',
    '#91c40f',
];
const result = colors.map((color) => color.replace(/\d/, '1'));
console.log(result);
```

**`SOULTION 2`**

You should always pick first solution but for another solution you can think below solution also.

```js
const colors = [
    '#9abc9c',
    '#9ecc71',
    '#9498db',
    '#9b59b6',
    '#967e22',
    '#974c3c',
    '#91c40f',
];
const result = colors.map((color) => `#1${color.split('').slice(2).join('')}`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this input is exactly what i want, thanks!