# Replace all chars with #, except for last 4

Tags: javascript, loops

```
function maskify(cc) {
    var dd = cc.toString();
    var hash = dd.replace((/./g), '#');
    for (var i = (hash.length - 4); i < hash.length; i++) {
        hash[i] = dd[i];
    }
    return hash;
}
```

I am trying to replace all chars with `#` except for last 4. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace a character in a string at a given index, `hash[i] = dd[i]` doesn't work. Strings are immutable in Javascript. See [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript) for some advice on that.

Answer (score 44):

You could do it like this:

```
dd.replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '#');
```

```js
var dd = 'Hello dude';
var replaced = dd.replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '#');
document.write(replaced);
```

Comment: @LukasDavid, it basically replaces all characters where there's more than 4 characters afterwards. So when it get to 4 characters before the end of the string, the regex will fail and won't replace those characters.

Answer (score 4):

If you find the solution, try this trick

```
function maskify(cc) {
  return cc.slice(0, -4).replace(/./g, '#') + cc.slice(-4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function maskify(cc) {
  let arr = cc.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 4; i++){
    arr[i] = '#';
  }
  return arr.join('');
}
```