# How can I get my program to swap a string with the key that is pressed down in a specific section of the string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm working on a hangman game in JavaScript and if the user guesses a letter correctly then I need to replace the "-" with the letter that the user has guessed in the corresponding position to where the letter is in the word. I can't seem to be able to replace the string, I can add the string on to the start or end of the "-"'s but when it comes to replacing them, I can't seem to figure out the solution. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Function that checks if the letter is in the word or not

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function textFunction(event)
{
if (event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91) 
{
    var guess = event.keyCode;
    var a = "a";
    var letterGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    if(sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess) >= 0){
        var letterLocation = sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess) + 1;
        progress.innerHTML += letterGuess;
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }
    alert(letterGuess);
} 
else 
{
    alert("Please type a letter");
}
});
```

Prints out the dashes

```
for (var i = 0; i < sayings[randomSaying].length; i++)
{
   progress.innerHTML += "-";
}
```

Variables

```
var progress = document.getElementById("dashes");


var sayings = [
    "cash on the nail",
    "charley horse",
    "double cross",
    "fit as a fiddle",
    "hands down",
    "if the cap fits",
    "mumbo jumbo",
    "see red",
    "stone the crows",
    "thick and thin",
]
sayings.toString();
var randomSaying = Math.floor(Math.random()*sayings.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of it (and drop the `+1` because its 0-based now)

```
if(sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess) >= 0){
    var letterLocation = sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess);
    var li = progress.innerHTML.split('');
    li[letterLocation] = letterGuess;
    progress.innerHTML = li.join('');
```

`.split('')` will split a string into its letters. So for "apple" you get `['a','p','p','l','e']`.

Then simply replace the position in the list `li[letterLocation]` with your letter, and `li.join('')` the list again.

To have it look for repeated letters, a `while` loop should do. We also need to start the search *after* the last match, so it will not find the same spot repeatedly.

```
if(sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess) >= 0) {
    var letterLocation = -1;
    while(sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess, letterLocation + 1) >= 0) {
        var letterLocation = sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess, letterLocation + 1);
        var li = progress.innerHTML.split('');
        li[letterLocation] = letterGuess;
        progress.innerHTML = li.join('');
    }
} else {
    alert("no");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this does work but only for the first letter it finds, how do I do this if there are more than one of the same letters in the word?

Comment: In the first line, replace `if` with `while`, so it will loop until no more concurrences of `letterGuess` are found.

Comment: Just tried this and the program wouldn't run at all, with no errors in the console

Comment: Oh, there is an `else`, so that can't work. Wait a sec, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the update, But I think there's something wrong with the code, everytime I try it now, nothing is replaced and the page crashes when I try to reload the page

Comment: There was a `+ 1` missing, I added it now. So it was finding the same spot over and over.

Comment: Argh, now I added it. Sorry. In two places, so it is each time `.indexOf(letterGuess, letterLocation + 1)`

Comment: That's It, Thankyou very much for bearing with me and helping me! One small problem is that it's not replacing the first letter if it's correct, but I'm sure that only requires a minor change.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be able to help with that would you? Iv'e got it to move a space up so that it starts where it should now, but not so it puts the letter at the start

Comment: Fixed it. We need to start at `var letterLocation = -1` now, because we are adding one, so that it starts to find letters at position `0` again.

Comment: Thankyou again! I was going the complete opposite direction and adding 1 on, I don't know why but It didn't make sense to start from -1 in my head

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `.split('')` the `sayings` into char arrays, then iterate through the array testing to see if its in the saying. Then you can build up a array of index's to replace.

example:

```
var dummyInput = 'a';

var sayings = [
  'cake'
];

//placeholder
var sayingMatches = [];

//go over all the sayings
for (var i = 0; i < sayings.length; i++) {
  var indexMatches = [];
  var sayingChars = sayings[i].split(''); //convert to char array

  //go over char array
  for (var j = 0; j < sayingChars.length; j++) {
    var letterToTest = sayingChars[j];
    if (letterToTest == dummyInput) {
      indexMatches.push(j); //push index of the match
    }
  }
  //push index of the saying you were just matching
  sayingMatches.push({
    sayingIndex: i,
    indexOfTheLettersWhichMatch: indexMatches
  });
}
```

This will give you an output of:

```
var sayingMatches = [
  {
    sayingIndex: 0,
    indexOfTheLettersWhichMatch: [2]
  }
];
```

From this you can then use replace to replace the '-'s with the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string at the corresponding index with substrings:

```
var index = 2;
var str = "012345";
var newstr;

newstr = str.substr(0, index) + 'a' + str.substr(index+1, str.length);

// result: 01a345
```

Just replace the index with the result of your `indexOf()` call. Remember that you will have to run this function multiple times if the letter appears more than once. Something like this inside your keydown call:

```
var reducer = sayings[randomSaying];
while (reducer.indexOf(letterGuess) >= 0) {
    index = reducer.indexOf(letterGuess);
    // ...
    reducer.replace(letterGuess, ''); // removes first instance of the letter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript) topic:
And as you can see there you need to define a `replaceAt()` to the `String.prototype` like this

> ```
> String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
>     return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
> }
> ```

and then all you need to do is call it from your code as such:

```
if(sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess) >= 0){
        var letterLocation = sayings[randomSaying].indexOf(letterGuess) + 1;
        progress.innerHTML = progres.innerHTML.replaceAt(letterLocation, letterGuess);

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try replacing the whole word? For instance, if the word is **apple** and you present is as

```
a _ _ l _
```

as soon as the user presses **p** you would replace the value of the element to

```
a p p l _
```

This would be much easier that replacing a single character within the value of an element.