# Insert a tag into string by character index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string, and I have to insert "div" into the string by using start/end values from an array.

```js
var str = "this is a simple string";

var places = [{
    "start": 0,
    "end": 3
  },
  {
    "start": 9,
    "end": 15
  }];

function insert(places, str) {
  // I tryed different approaches like this:
  str = str.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var start = item.start;
    var end = item.end;
    
    var newStr = '<div>'+str[start] + '</div>' + str.slice(end);
    str = newStr;
  });
  $('.h').html(str);
  // I need to get output str as:
  // "<div>this</div> is a <div>simple</div> string"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h"></div>
```

How can I do it using splice or foreach functions?

Comment: Can you show your code attempt?

Comment: It'd be nice if your code snippet worked.

Comment: It works, it just does nothing because it's not really a code attempt

Comment: @happymacarts It doesn't work. He doesn't have a function name - SyntaxError

Comment: I must have seen it after his edit.

Comment: @Mike You have `places[0].end-places[0].start === 3`, but `'this'.length === 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to write `0, 4` and `10, 16` (because string `'this'` is of length 4, not 3) it becomes

```
var str = "this is a simple string";
var places = [{
  "start": 0,
  "end": 4
}, {
  "start": 10,
  "end": 16
}];

function insert(places, str){
    var starts = [], ends = [];

    places.forEach(place => {
        starts.push(place.start);
        ends.push(place.end);
    });

    return str.split('').map((chr, pos) => {
        if(starts.indexOf(pos) != -1) chr = '<div>' + chr;
        if(ends.indexOf(pos) != -1) chr = '</div>' + chr;
        return chr;
    }).join('')
}

console.log(insert(places, str)); // <div>this</div> is a <div>simple</div> string
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `str` as array of single letters and apply in a loop over places the wanted tags to the letters. Then join all items together and return the string.

This solution works for random sorted `places`.

```js
function insert(places, str) {
    return places.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.start] = '<div>' + r[a.start];
        r[a.end] += '</div>';
        return r;
    }, str.split('')).join('');
}

var str = "this is a simple string",
    places = [{ "start": 0, "end": 3 }, { "start": 10, "end": 15 }];

console.log(insert(places, str));
```

One solution without reduce:

```js
function insert(places, str) {
    var r = str.split('');
    places.forEach(function (a) {
        r[a.start] = '<div>' + r[a.start];
        r[a.end] += '</div>';
    });
    return r.join('');
}

var str = "this is a simple string",
    places = [{ "start": 0, "end": 3 }, { "start": 10, "end": 15 }];

console.log(insert(places, str));
```

For further reading, you could have a look into this answer, why an array of letters might be faster than string functions: [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747861/1447675)

Comment: Elegant solution, @Nina. Using `reduce` in this manner should be much preferred to the brittle, in-place string mutation via `forEach` as in my snippet.

Comment: I didn't downvoted your answer, but It doesn't work as OP expect. If you look carefully, expected output is `<div>this</div> is a <div>simple</div> string`, and not `<div>this</div> is a<div> simple</div> string` which your function gives

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 that's b/c the original post had the wrong index for the start of his second `<div>` tag. Nina's code works perfectly well and will output as expected if `places[1].start = 10`. @Nina someone was carpet-bombing negative votes to all answers. Mine received 2 down-votes, as did another poster who deleted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of accomplishing your goal, using `Array#forEach` and successively mutating the string w/ an 11 chars shift for each `<div></div>` tag added.

```
var str = "this is a simple string";

// change place into an array of objects
var place = [
  {
    "start": 0,
    "end": 3
  },
  {
    "start": 10,
    "end": 15
  }
];

function insert(place, str) {
  var shift = 0;
  place.forEach(function(p){
    str = str.substring(0,p.start+shift) + "<div>" + 
    str.substring(p.start+shift,p.end+shift+1) + "</div>" + str.substring(p.end+shift+1);
    shift += 11; //shift 11 chars for each match
  });
  return str;
}

console.log( insert(place,str) );
```

Note this solution depends upon the `places` array holding indices in *ascending order*.

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows... though i would recommend you to chose your string indices better. Especially it would be better if the `end` index doesn't point the last character but the one beyond. I have amended the data accordingly. We are adding an offset of 11 for every round of the reduce since our string gains "`<div></div>`" many (11) characters every round.

```js
var str = "this is a simple string";

  place = [{
            "start": 0,
              "end": 4
           },
           {
            "start": 10,
              "end": 16
           }],
 newStr = place.reduce((s,o,i) => s.slice(0,o.start + (i*11)) + "<div>" +
                                  s.slice(o.start + (i*11), o.end + (i*11)) + "</div>" +
                                  s.slice(o.end + (i*11)), str);
console.log(newStr);
```

Of course it might be generalized to insert any tag.