# Javascript Replace string

Tags: javascript, replace, markdown

Here is the the Mardown text..

```
![sample text](/api/article/58933542dbac1da7eba747e0/file/58933542dbac1da7eba747e1/binary/A3DD9420-C5BA-426A-A51A-296C263440FF.png).fgfgfdgdfgdfgfg fg.<video controls poster='tempfile://827e9ff4-07ef-f9c1-a4c2-5d4f8fcb5754'><source src='tempfile://d23228e7-a683-befc-724b-96f57f5459e7' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

In the above string need to replace

```
 <video controls poster='tempfile://827e9ff4-07ef-f9c1-a4c2-5d4f8fcb5754'><source src='tempfile://d23228e7-a683-befc-724b-96f57f5459e7' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

with empty using javascript (Replace) regular expression..

```
 function RemoveContentText(text, link) {
    return text.replace(/(!\[.*?\]\()(.+?)(\))/g, function (whole, a, b, c)  {

        if (whole == link) return '';
        else return whole;
    });
}
```

Here text is the Mardowntext and link is the string which needs to be replaced by empty..

Comment: Can you please share your efforts?

Comment: For the Regex what about `const regex = /<video.*<\/video>/g;` ?

Comment: @getjackx Thanks for the replay , but the markdown string may contain mutiple video , so need to identity specific video and replace with empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
/<\s*video[^>]*>\s*(?:<\s*source[^>]*>\s*)*<\s*\/\s*video\s*>/ig
```

It should match all possible video tags with only source tags inside of them.

[regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) is a good place for testing such regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with indexOf()  to get the indexes of video tag and then try replacing.
Example for find:

`var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe."; var n =
str.indexOf("welcome");`
answer: 13

[replacing with index position](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)