# Don't understand why replace() method is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, replace

Working on the following problem:

Create a function called `alienLanguage` where the input will be a `str` and the output should capitalize all letters except for the last letter of each word

`alienLanguage("My name is John")` should return `"My NAMe Is JOHn"`

This is what I have coded:

```
function alienLanguage(str){
  var words = str.toUpperCase().split(' ').map(function (a) {
    return a.replace(a[a.length - 1], a[a.length - 1].toLowerCase())
  });
  return words.join(' ');
}
```

All of the example test cases work except for the following:

```
Expected: '\'THIs Is An EXAMPLe\'', instead got: '\'THIs Is An eXAMPLE\''
```

Why is the e in `eXAMPLE` turning lowercase? Shouldn't everything automatically turn upperCase ?

edit: I just realized that there are 2 `e`'s and the first one is being replaced. How can I replace the last `e`? and isn't the last character specified already?

Comment: You want assignment instead of replace.

Comment: the trouble is, there are two e's in example - beginning and end ... eagle fails ... as does edge, and abba and otto and trumpet - see the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> isn't the last character specified already?

No, you've only specified what character to replace, not where. `replace` searches the string for the expression.

> How can I replace the last e?

Don't use `replace` at all. It does construct a new string anyway, and you can do that much easier:

```
function alienLanguage(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(function(a) {
    return a.slice(0, -1).toUpperCase() + a.slice(-1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(' ');
}
```

You also could use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), but would use it with regular expression:

```
function alienLanguage(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase().replace(/.\b/g, function(last) {
//                                 ^^^^^^ matches all characters before a word boundary
    return last.toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to split the string into words. Just use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex to upper-case all letters that are immediately followed by another letter, like this:

```
function alienLanguage(str){
    return str.replace(/(\w)(?=\w)/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is searching using a pattern (or regular expression) and it replaces all occurrences.

Instead, you want to truncate and create a new string, which is known as assignment in other languages (but strings in JS are immutable). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript) for more details.

Comment: `is searching using a regular expression` - not in the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring`. Your `replace` replaces and replaces the first occurrence of the last character in the words -- definitely what you're after:

```
function alienLanguage(str){
  var words = str.toUpperCase().split(' ').map(function (a) {
    return a.length ? a.substring(0, a.length - 2) + a[a.length - 1].toLowerCase() : a;
  });
  return words.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @TatsuyukiIshi said, you need to change the use of `replace()` for regular assignment. For extra help, here is an updated version of your `alienLanguage` function:

```
function alienLanguage(str){
    return str.toUpperCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
        return word.slice(0, -1) + word.substr(-1).toLowerCase()
    }).join(' ')
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5zfLg2zL/)

---

Extra notes:

`word.slice(0,-1)` returns the word minus the last character.

`word.substr(-1)` returns the last character as a string.

`.map()` returns an array, so you can call `join()` directly on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the letter, just concatenate the uppercase part of the string up to the last letter with the lowercased last letter.

This should do the trick:

```
function alienLanguage(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(function(a) {
    return a.slice(0, -1).toUpperCase() + a.slice(-1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
function alienLanguage(str){
   var words = str.toUpperCase().split(' ').map(function (a) {
   return a.substr(0, a.length - 1) +a[a.length - 1].toLowerCase() + a.substr(a.length - 1 + 1);
   });
  return words.join(' ');
 }
```