# .replace is not a function error in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, replace, undefined

in javascript the following is returning an error saying that hello.replaceAt is not a function, that hello.replaceAt is undefined.

```
    var hello = 'Hello World';
    alert(hello.replaceAt(2, "!!"));
```

Why is this not working? Thanks.

Comment: replace is a function replace**At** is not  ... (unless you create one or use a library that implements one)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Using **replace()**:

```
var hello = 'Hello World!!';
    alert(hello.replace("!!",'??'));
```

If you want to replace all matchs in a string you can use this funct

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Because `.replace()` just replace first match.
Cheers

Comment: i would like to replace part of the string at a certain index

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("!!", "...!!");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo">Hello world!!</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Check this out. Help you to get some idea.

Greetings!