# Function only returning first letter capitalised

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is meant to do this:

```
accum("abcd");    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty"); // "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
```

We can see the first "for" loop repeats each substring by it's current `(index + 1)`. It pushes it to the array and the output would be `[ 'a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd' ]`

It is then obvious that I need to iterate over this array and capitalise each string which I have done by the second for loop below. 
The problem is when I return the array it is returning like this: `[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]`

It is returning the first substring of each string but it isn't returning the rest of them.

```
function accum(s) {
    var splitstring = s.split("")
    var newarray = []
    for(var i = 0; i < splitstring.length; i++) {
        newarray.push(splitstring[i].repeat(i + 1))
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
        newarray[i]  = newarray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()    
    }
    return newarray
}
accum("abcd")
```

Comment: You are overwriting the whole string in your second loop. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript) to see how to do it.

Comment: ` newarray[i]  = newarray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() ` <-- well that seems to be your problem since you replace it with just the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use second `for` loop. Just use `map()` on the returned array.

```js
function accum(s) {
  var splitstring = s.split("");
  var newarray = [];
  for(var i= 0; i < splitstring.length; i++) {
    newarray.push(splitstring[i].repeat(i + 1))
  }
  return newarray.map(j=>j[0].toUpperCase()+ j.slice(1)).join('-');
}

console.log(accum("abcd"));
```

Comment: Sorry, see above: ---> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"

Comment: @monkeybanana, I have updated my answer. Please have a look...thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're overwriting the string with only the first character. you need to concatenate the rest of the string.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
    newarray[i]  = newarray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newarray[i].slice(1);
  }
```

Here's a shorter version of your code:

```js
function accum(s) {
  return s.split("").map((ss, i) => ss.toUpperCase() + ss.repeat(i)).join("-");
}

console.log(accum("abcd"));
```

It also adds the separator that you seem to want. If you actually wanted the array, then remove `.join("-")`.