# Im trying to replace a particular char within an index of an array.

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to replace the first '0' in index 0 of the array I made called 'bits'.

```
bits = ['01010'];

console.log(bits[0].charAt(1));

bits[0].charAt(0) = '9'; // <-Not working

console.log(bits[0].charAt(0));
```

What would I replace the third line of code with above to accomplish this?

The final console log should return '9'

[(JSBIN link)](http://jsbin.com/safaguf/edit?js,console)

Also str.replaceAt doesnt work as well

Comment: Why? Why not a nested array or a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Comment: Strings are immutable. Even if that statement had been `bits[0][0] = '9'`, the assignment would have been a no-op in non-strict mode and thrown a `TypeError` in strict mode.

Comment: charAt is a function that return a value. You cannot assign a value to it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bits = ['01010'];
console.log(bits); //["01010"]
bits[0] = bits[0].replace('0','9');
console.log(bits); //["91010"]
```

Comment: That would not guarantee the 0th index being replaced if the `bits` string was a different value.

Answer (score 4):

```
 bits[0] = "9" + bits[0].substr(1);
```

---

Alternatively you can write a replace function:

```
function replace(str, replace, start, end){
  return str.substr(0, start) + replace + str.substr(end || start + replace.length);
}

bits[0] = replace(bits[0], "9", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

make a copy of string to replace any character . also a custom function "setCharAt" needs to be defined

```
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

after declaring the functions execute below given code to replace character at "0" index

```
bits[0]=setCharAt(bits[0],0,9)
```

after doing this final console.log will return "9"