# to replace or remove double,single quotes from string in php/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, trim

I need to remove all double quotes,single quotes using jQuery AJAX in with google language translator. when i change onchange() it does not translate the string or character if double quotes found,and i am also used in php but not getting expected result.

i am used php' string related function but not getting result

HTML CODE :

```
<select name="langid" id="langid<@=review_id@>" class="guest clearfix" style="width: 150px;height: 29px;" onchange='translate_text("<@=review_id@>","<@=review_title@>","<@=your_view@>","<@=neg_review@>");'>
```

PHP CODE :

```
<?php

public function translate_text()
{
   try
        {
            $positive = $_REQUEST['positivereview'];
            $negative = $_REQUEST['negativereview'];
            $title = $_REQUEST['title'];


            $translate_into = $_REQUEST['lang']; 


            $var = new translate($translate_from,$translate_into); 

            $ar = array();
            if($title)
            {

                $ar['title'] = $var->get($title);
            }
            if($positive)
            {

                $ar['positivereview'] = $var->get($positive);   
            }   
            if($negative)
            {

                $ar['negativereview'] = $var->get($negative);   
            }   
            print_r(json_encode($ar));
            exit(0);

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->log->logIt($this->module."-".""."-".$e);
        }       
    }

?>
```

JS/JQUERY CODE :

```
 function translate_text($review_id,$review_title,$your_view,$neg_review) 
    {


     var sel = jQuery('#langid'+$review_id).val();
         var url=serverurl+'index.php/feedback';
            showLoadingBar();
            if(sel == 0)
            sel = 'en';



     var passDataAsStr="opcode=translate_text&positivereview="+
    $your_view+"&negativereview="+$neg_review+"&title="+$review_title+"&lang="+sel;


                jQuery.ajax({


             type: "POST",
                     url: url,
                    //async : false,
                    data: passDataAsStr,
                    success: function(response) {
                    hideLoadingBar();
                    // console.log(response);
                        jQuery('#btnclose'+$review_id).show();
                        jQuery('#trans_div'+$review_id).show();
                        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                        console.log(res['title']);
                        console.log(res['positivereview']);
                        console.log(res['negativereview']);
                        jQuery('#titleid_'+$review_id).text(res['title']);
                        jQuery('#positiveid'+$review_id).text(res['positivereview']);
                        jQuery('#negativeid'+$review_id).text(res['negativereview']);

                          }
                  });
    }
```

When I want change the language translator it does not change,i am using like this
`var $review_title = this.$review_title.replace(/['"]+/g, "");` but i don't know how to pass `.replace() in parameter in ajax jquery. to change the review title in jquery and in php also not get result

i want this type of output.

input like this : `"New "home" away from home when in village"`

output must be this :  `New home away from home when in village`

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

to sort out in `php` or `jquery` side or any html special character

Comment: I suggest you to take a look to one of my question if you're interested to replace quotes by "correct" quotation marks, as the "correct" ones shouldn't create this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816069/replace-double-quotes-by-quotation-marks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.replace(/"|'/g,'');` to remove double or single quotes:

```js
var str = `New "home" away from home when in village's`;
var res = str.replace(/"|'/g,'');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: can u implement in my ajax jquery  ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$str = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $str);
```

And If your string is having only characters and numbers then you can use:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/", "", html_entity_decode($str ));
```

Comment: how can i implement in php like this ??  $positive = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/", "", html_entity_decode($$_REQUEST['positivereview'] ));

Comment: yes.. Just remove extra `$` from `$$_REQUEST['positivereview']`

Comment: error continue runnig   Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Check for Closing bracket (`)`)

Comment: there is no any issue of `()` @ Sambhaji Katrajkar

Comment: check `$_REQUEST['positivereview']`  value.. if it is coming or not