# Javascript replace not working in array string element

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Here my array :

```
let model = ["xxx","xxx"];
```

I want to replace the second 'x' in the string of the second element of the array by 'o'.

I tried this :

```js
let model = ["xxx", "xxx"];

console.log(model[1][2])
// -> output : x -> OK

model[1][2] = model[1][2].replace('x', 'o')

console.log(model);
// -> output : ["xxx", "xxx"] -> ???
```

I tried this too :

```js
let model = ["xxx", "xxx"];

console.log(model[1][2])
// -> output : x

model[1][2] = 'o'

console.log(model);
// -> output : ["xxx", "xxx"]
```

Why is not working ? Thank you !

Comment: replace method expects a regexp as it's first parameter.

Comment: I got the same result with model[1][2] = 'o' @GhoulAhmed

Comment: @Pierre it also accept string, not necessarly only regex

Comment: that's not how you alter a string.

Comment: strings are in their very nature immutable. You have to update `model[1]` with the changed string. You can not just change one character in a string.

Comment: Why do all the comments keep disappearing from this thread? You would need to replace the entire string using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: Thank's for your help !