# Setting new value to str.charAt()

Tags: javascript, string, indexing, char, charat

I am trying to set the value of a character at a certain index in a string with a new character and I was wondering if it was possible with charAt() method. Something like this. `str.charAt(1)` will return string "*e*" at first.

```
let str = "hello";
str.charAt(1) = 'a';
```

`str.charAt(1)` will then return string "*a*".

My expected result is that the new string reads "hallo". But this results in an Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. So is it simply not possible with this method?

Comment: You cannot mutate a String in JavaScript. You can only create a new one, and assign it back to the `str` variable explicitly

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks I understand that they are immutable

Answer (score 0):

[charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) is a function on String prototype,and you are trying to overriding it by that syntax; `charAt()` will return the character at the index and it is getter, not a setter; so you need to define your own custom method to achieve that, either by defining a pure function like snippet below or by defining it on `String.prototype` so you can use on any string;

```js
let str = "hello";

function replaceStrAtIndex( str, index, letter ){
  let modifiedStr = [...str];
  modifiedStr[index] = letter;
  return modifiedStr.join('')
}
console.log(replaceStrAtIndex(str, 1, 'a'))
```

---

or defining on string prototype:

```js
String.prototype.replaceCharAt = function replaceStrAtIndex( index, letter ){
  let modifiedStr = [...this];
  modifiedStr[index] = letter;
  return modifiedStr.join('')
}

let str = "hello";
console.log(str.replaceCharAt( 1, 'a'))
```