# Convert date string of 'yymmdd' format to 'MM-DD-YYYY'

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Hi I have strings representing dates in the format of 'yymmdd' i.e. '200421' represents 04-21-2020. How can I convert this to a format of 'MM-DD-YYYY' which is commonly used? I'm thinking this should be simple enough to use Date or momentjs, rather than getting creative and using substrings, etc..

I've been playing around with momentjs on http://jsfiddle.net/v9n4pL8s/1/

and have tried `var now = moment('200421').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
alert(now);`

but it seems to be all trial and error. Anybody have a simple way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you [have to](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) pass the date format as the second argument.

```js
const date = moment('200421', 'YYMMDD').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 2nd argument has to be caps. i.e. 'YYMMDD', but this works and is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```js
var str = '200421';

function format(date) {
    return date.slice(2, 4) + '-' + date.slice(4) + '-20' + date.slice(0, 2);
}

format(str); // "04-21-2020"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to use substring but, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/13108751) can be useful.