# Cannot replace single emoji from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string called `completionBar` which contains this:

```
let completionBar = `〚⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛〛`;
```

I'm trying to replace a single ⬛ with ⬜, so I tried:

```
completionBar.replace(/\U+2B1B/, 'U+2B1C');
```

but nothing happen, what I did wrong?

Comment: The problem is that the + sign has a special meaning for the regex engine,

Comment: Doing this using the unicode encodings would be: `completionBar.replace(/\u2B1B/, String.fromCharCode("0x2B1C"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/⬛/g` in `.replace()`.

I would try as the following if you want to replace all:

```js
let completionBar = `〚⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛〛`;

const result  = completionBar.replace(/⬛/g, '⬜');

console.log(result)
```

If you need only the first to replace:

```js
let completionBar = `〚⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛〛`;

const result  = completionBar.replace('⬛', '⬜');

console.log(result)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: oh really nice! how can I replace just one emojy?

Comment: @sfarzoso Just extended my answer with that.

Comment: thanks! just last question: it is possible replace the last emojy of the string?

Comment: You can get the last index with `lastIndexOf()` then using the answer's solution from here: [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use `escape` and `unescape` function to show exactly the string code. It easy to debug and maintain the code.

```js
let completionBar = `〚⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛〛`;

let escapeCompletionBar = escape(completionBar).replace(/u2B1B/g, 'u2B1C');

let result = unescape(escapeCompletionBar);
```