# copying variables node.js

Tags: node.js, variables, let

I have such part of code

```
console.log(b);
let c = b.substr(0);
console.log(b[b.length - 1] + ' ' + c[Math.floor(c.length / 2)]);
c[Math.floor(c.length / 2)] = b[b.length - 1];
console.log(b[b.length - 1] + ' ' + c[Math.floor(c.length / 2)]);
//some code changing c
console.log(c);
```

And it seems like c and b are the same part of memory, because `console.log(c);` and `console.log(b);` give the same result, and two other console.logs give same results, when the second one should obviously give two same values (it gives different ones). How to copy a value of a variable correctly and without making something weird like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b))`? Is there a time- and memory- effective way to do that in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substr function returns a new String (new object), hence c and b are not the same objects.

Also, changing a String by assigning a different character to some index doesn't work as it doesn't change the original object.

If what you seek to do is replacing a character at a specific index, here's a useful post:
[How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Comment: ahhhh. I cannot change strings in JS. Did not know that, thanks a lot

Comment: sure, no problem :)