# How to convert 123456789 to 123***789 in typescript/ javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

is there any method or function that able to convert such scenario? My project need to display userID in this format, the first 3 int/string and last 3 int/string should able to display the number, while middle part should be hashed with *.

Comment: This can be done with the built in substring functions; there are some libraries out there for masking text as well that could help. Can you show us your code attempt?

Comment: Maybe try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: Also what will you do if the "userid" is 6 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution it is just by splitting the text into three sets first middle last and convert the middle

```
const convertText = (text) => {
  const firstSet = text.slice(0, 3);
  const lastSet = text.slice(text.length - 3, text.length);
  const middleSet = text.slice(3, text.length - 3);
  var starSet = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < middleSet.length; i++) {
    starSet = starSet.concat("*");
  }
  const convertedText = firstSet.concat(starSet, lastSet);
  return convertedText;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JS strings are immutable, you can only accomplish this by building a new string. One of the easiest ways to do this is by splitting the string into individual characters and inserting them into an array, since arrays are mutable. You can do this using `Array.from`.

You can then modify individual characters. In your case, since you want to change a range of values so that they are all the same value, you can use `Array.fill` which will fill a subsection of the array with a value.

Now that you've changed the values, you just have to recombine them into a string, which you can do using `Array.join`.

```
let hideMiddle = (str) => Array.from(str).fill("*", 3, -3).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, hope the below code helps

```js
const slice = (str) =>{
    let total = ""
    let error = false
    let errorMessage = ""
    if(str != null && str !=""){
        error = false
        let firstThree = str.slice(0, 3)
        let lastThree = str.slice(str.length-3, str.length)
        total = `${firstThree}***${lastThree}`
    }else{
        error = true
        errorMessage = "Please fill the str perimter."
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total
}

// Calling Function
console.log(slice("12345678"))
```