# affecting values into arrays isn't working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make Ceaser cipher that shifts the input by the value you chose, for example you chose 3, and the program will shift letters by 3 to the back, so i created an array type variable *alpha* that contains letters from a to z, and create two other variable one is the shift value and the other is a string filled by the user, my idea was to compare each letter from the input with alpha and if they match then i will replace it with the shifted value.

`input[i] = alpha[j-shift_value];`

i wanted to do it as simple as possible but for some reason it's not working, I'll provide a code snippet.

```js
var ClearText = document.getElementById("txt_clr").value;
var DecValue = document.getElementById("valeur_dec").value;
var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var longeur = ClearText.length;

// alpha[0]=a;
// alpha[26]=z;

var i;

function decalager() {

  for (i = 0; i < longeur; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
      if (ClearText[i] == alpha[j]) {
        ClearText[i] = alpha[j - DecValue];
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(ClearText);
  document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = ClearText;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #002b36;
  display: flex;
}

.centrer {
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  color: wheat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

textarea {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

button,
input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 113px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centrer">
    <p>Décalage: </p> <input id="valeur_dec" type="text"> <button onclick="decalager()">Chiffrer</button>
    <p>Texte claire: </p>
    <textarea id="txt_clr" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <p>Texte avec Décalage: </p>
    <textarea id="resultat" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not convert to ASCII code using [`chatCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) subtract 3 then convert back to characters using [`fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Comment: first split (change string to array), then do your process, then join back again.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript.

```js
const greeting = "Hello"
console.log(greeting[0]) // H
greeting[0] = "A"
console.log(greeting[0]) // H
```

You can turn your string into an array, modify it and then turn it back into a string again.

```js
const greeting = "Hello"
const greetingArray = [...greeting]
console.log(greetingArray) // ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
const alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
const shift = 3
for(const [charIndex, char] of Object.entries(greetingArray)) {
    const alphaIndex = alpha.indexOf(char.toLowerCase())
    greetingArray[charIndex] = alpha[(alphaIndex + shift) % alpha.length] 
}
const shiftedGreeting = greetingArray.join("")
console.log(shiftedGreeting) // khoor
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so you will need a function to replace a letter at each index. It's easiest to define this as a method on the String prototype Object.
Then the action function will need an input parameter, in this case you would want to input `ClearText` and `DecValue` to shift the string by, and this will call the `replaceAt()` method.

```
var ClearText = document.getElementById("txt_clr").value;
var DecValue = document.getElementById("valeur_dec").value;
var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var longeur = ClearText.length;

// alpha[0]=a;
// alpha[25]=z;

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

function decalager(clearText, decValue) {

  for (let i = 0; i < longeur; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
      if (clearText[i] == alpha[j]) {
        clearText = clearText.replaceAt(i, alpha[j-decValue])
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(clearText);
  document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = clearText;
}
```

Then call this with `decalager(ClearText, DecValue);`.
Read more about the replaceAt() method here: [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simply `.split('')` both strings (input and alphabet) then compare array to array. then .`join('')` the final result (array to string).

But make sure to include `(j - devValue) > 0` in your condition because you don't want to go negative on index. Or you can just simply do `alpha[0]` if `j - decValue` is negative.

```js
var stringOne = "apppele"
var stringTwo = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var decValue = 2;

var stringOneArray = stringOne.split('');
var stringTwoArray = stringTwo.split('');

for (i = 0; i < stringOneArray.length; i++){
  for (j = 0; j < stringTwoArray.length; j++) {
    if (stringOneArray[i] == stringTwoArray[j] && (j - decValue > 0)) {
          console.log("index #" + i + " (" + stringOneArray[i] + ") changed to " + stringTwoArray[j - decValue]);
      stringOneArray[i] = stringTwoArray[j - decValue]
    }
  }
}
  var stringOneJoined = stringOneArray.join('');
  console.log("Final result: " + stringOneJoined);
```