# How to find index on a string and replace?

Tags: javascript

How can we find by index and replace it with a string? (see expected outputs below)

I tried the code below, but it also replaces the next string. [(from these stack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

var hello = "hello world";
console.log(hello.replaceAt(2, "!!")); // He!!o World
```

**Expected output:**

```
var toReplace = "!!";

1. "Hello World" ==> .replaceAt(5, toReplace) ===> "Hello!!World"
2. "Hello World" ==> .replaceAt(2, toReplace) ===> "He!!lo World"
```

**Note:** `toReplace` variable could be dynamic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Comment: @YosvelQuinteroArguelles already add that link as reference in my description. pls check. working output is not I want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second substring index should be `index` + 1:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + 1);
}

console.log("Hello World".replaceAt(5, "!!"))
console.log("Hello World".replaceAt(2, "!!"))
console.log("Hello World".replaceAt(2, "!!!"))
```

Comment: it only works for *!!*, it does not work in dynamic or in other string length like *!!@@*. I updated my description :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add the string as a parameter in an ES6 function?

```
const replaceAt = (index, replacement, string) => {
    return string[:index] + replacement + string[index+1:]
}
```