# How to change the value of innerText at a particular index?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the string displayed in the frontend by using a function in javascript.

```
let displayword = document.getElementById("displayword”)
    console.log(displayword.innerText)     //apple
```

Say, I want the change the letter “l” to something else say “i” but keep the rest of the letters unchanged how do I go around this?

Things I have tried

```
displayword.innerText[3] = “i”           // -----does nothing----
```

I am confused why the above code using index does nothing, while the below does something

```
dash.innerText += “i”      //applei
```

Extra question: Why does the above code using =+ change the formatting of the innerText? I want to keep the large font but it changes to regular font of the element (here I am using h1).

Thank you:)

Comment: The += operator is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Comment: a string it not an array, its not like in other languages an array of chars, just look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) documentation, especially [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

In many languages, Strings can't be modified directly. Instead you "change" it by creating a *new* string composed of parts of the original.

As for how you'd do it in your case:

```js
var text = displayWord.innerText;
text = text.slice(0, 3) + 'i' + text.slice(4) // apple -> appie
displayWord.innerText = text;
```

[Edited code slightly]

Answer (score 0):

```
displayword.innerText = displayword.innerText.replace(oldCharacter, newCharacter);
```

To replace all occurrences:

```
displayword.innerText = displayword.innerText.replaceAll(oldCharacter, newCharacter);
```