# Regular expression who change the third slash in to a space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I need a regular expression who substitute the third slash in to a space.

To be more specific I've this case:
A Date = `28/11/2022/11:40` and I wish that the date will be in this format `28/11/2022 11:40`.

As written before I expect this way `28/11/2022 11:40` ( without the slash between the time and the date )

Comment: If it's always dd/mm/yyyy then use `substring` to replace that character:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/2181514

Answer (score 1):

There are again a few ways to do what you need.

You can use `String.prototype.substring` if the date is always in the same format or you can use a regular expression to handle other cases. If you are working with dates a lot in your application I'd recommend a simple library like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/). It's lightweight and you could use `.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')` method to format your date.

```js
const date = '28/11/2022/11:40';

const formatDate = (date) => {
    return `${date.substring(0, 10)} ${date.substring(11)}`;
};

const formatDateWithRegex = (date) => {
    return date.replace(/^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})\/(\d{1,2}:\d{2})$/, "$1 $2");
};

console.log('Without RegExp: ',formatDate(date));
console.log('With RegExp:', formatDateWithRegex(date));
```

The regex I've used here is probably suboptimal but it groups your MM/DD/YYYY date and HH:mm as a separate groups and then returns them with a space being the separator (`$1` - first group, `$2` - second group).