# How to change the last character of string?

Tags: javascript, string

Here's my problem:

```
let a = "abcd2";
a[a.length - 1] = "0";
console.log(a);
```

the output is still "abcd2", but I want it to be "abcd0", this code isn't working, what should i do?

I also tried to use `slice(-1)` to get last character of string, but it shows error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: the string is immutable, you can slice the string and concatenate with 0